# Inconsistent risk difference confidence interval and pvalue from Chi2-test

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, chi-squared-test, survey, risk-difference

I am using the `svyglm` function in the survey package in R to compute a risk difference in proportions, 95% confidence interval and p-value. The outcome is binary and seeking the % risk difference between male and females. The method suggested by Thomas Lumley is by using the svyglm() for a linear model, explained here: stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/271014.html

My output as follows:

```r
svy_design<- svydesign(ids = ~block, strata = ~strata, weights = ~wt,  data=data_all,nest = TRUE, fpc = NULL)  

options(survey.lonely.psu="certainty")

riskmodel<-svyglm(as.numeric(binary_outcome)~Gender, design=svy_design, data=data_all)
```

The output as follows:

```r
Call:
svyglm(formula = as.numeric(binary_outcome) ~ Gender, 
    design = svy_design, data = data_all)

Survey design:
svydesign(ids = ~blocks, strata = ~strata, weights = ~wt, 
    data = data_all, nest = TRUE, fpc = NULL)

Coefficients:
                       Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            0.014101   0.003891   3.624 0.000375 ***
Genderfemale           0.059430   0.039972   1.487 0.138771    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.01723948)

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

```
confint(riskmodel)
```

```
                              2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept)             0.006424551 0.0217782
Genderfemale           -0.019429398 0.1382897
```

The confidence interval contains 0 and the p-value is >0.05.

The chi2-test using second order rao-scott correction gives a pvalue <0.01. Output:

```r
svychisq(~binary_outcome+Gender,design = svy_design)
```

```r
    Pearson's X^2: Rao & Scott adjustment

data:  svychisq(~binary_outcome+ Gender, design = svy_design)
F = 8.5087, ndf = 1, ddf = 200, p-value = 0.003938
```

The wald p-value is >0.05:

```r
    Design-based Wald test of association

data:  svychisq(~binary_outcome+ Gender, design = svy_design,     statistic = "Wald")
F = 1.9138, ndf = 1, ddf = 200, p-value = 0.1681
```

I understand that the 95% confidence interval from the `svyglm` function and pearson chi2-test with rao-scott correction, are based on different assumptions, one reports exact confidence intervals and p-value is approximate. My question is how to interpret these differences, and whether the risk difference, 95% ci from `svyglm` and p-value from chi2 test can be reported together? Or should the pvalue be reported from the `svyglm` output? Also, is there any guidance on selecting the appropriate statistic for the survey weighted chi2 test?

Comment: What marginalization are you seeking that makes ordinary unweighted estimates inadequate?

Comment: "The confidence interval contains 1 and the p-value is >0.05" doesn't correctly describe the binary `svyglm()` model. The `gender` coefficient in that model is for the change in _log-odds_ of the binary outcome between males and females. The null value for that coefficient would thus be 0, not 1, and the displayed _p_ value of 0.01 is correct and similar to the chi-squared result.

Comment: Apologies, the outputs been corrected which was based on a different sample. The p-value is 0.13877. Also, the risk difference was calculated based on this post by Thomas Lumley: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-March/271014.html

Comment: @FrankHarrel I used svyglm as the samples were selected using a complex survey design

Comment: Please double-check that the data and the corresponding `svy_design` objects were the same for the calls that you now show to `svyglm()` and `svychisq()`. I know that I occasionally get into trouble when I use the same names for different objects, and the previous version of `svyglm()` results you showed did agree well with what you have continued to show for `svychisq()`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The previous version was based on a different sample I had copied over where the issue was not there, but the rest of the output (pvalues and confidence intervals etc) shown are correct. The issue is not unexpected, as the 95% CI for a risk difference is based on the exact confidence intervals and p-values from survey weighted pearson chi2 test are approximate. My question was more on how to interpret these differences.

Comment: @s.g I know you used `svyglm`; I was asked about your intended estimand and why the use of sample weights, which are used for marginalization vs. regular covariate adjustment ignoring the weights, which is fully conditional.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thanks very much for the reply. The survey was collected using a complex sampling design and to ensure our estimates of risk and risk difference are nationally representative I did apply weights. The intended estimand is the risk difference of the outcome variable by gender, and I used the svyglm to estimate this risk difference using survey weighted linear regression (Thomas Lumleys post referred to above). I'm not aware of an alternative to this or perhaps if a different method may be used to generate these confidence intervals for risk difference.

Comment: Also, there seem to be quite a few different chi2 statistics, the weighted pearson chi2 test is what I used with second order rao-scott correction, I'm wondering if perhaps a different statistic should be used. How does one select the appropriate chi2 statistic for survey analysis? The documentation has the following options "statistic = c("F","Chisq","Wald","adjWald","lincom","saddlepoint")". Thank you

Comment: @s.g the use of weights to obtain "representative" estimates always needs to be questioned a bit.  If risk varies over the factors forming the weights, then factor-specific risks are often more useful.